# Gedmo Tree Nested & Doctrine Behaviors Translation

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a simple problem but, i don't found how to resolve it, 
so i use Doctrine Behaviors to apply a system translation on my project, and Gedmo\Tree to apply the system of category left-right.

This is my action :

```php
public function menuAction()
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $repo = $em->getRepository('ProductsBundle:Category');
        $options = array(
            'decorate' => true,
            'rootOpen' => '<ul>',
            'rootClose' => '</ul>',
            'childOpen' => '<li>',
            'childClose' => '</li>',
            'representationField' => 'id',
            'nodeDecorator' => function($node) {
                return '<a href="category/'.$node['id'].'">'.$node['id'].'</a>';
            }
        );
        $htmlTree = $repo->childrenHierarchy(
            null,
            false,
            $options
        );
        // $tree = $repo->buildTree($query->getArrayResult(), $options);
        $categories = $em->getRepository("ProductsBundle:Category")->getCategoryHiearchy();
        return $this->render('ProductsBundle:Public:Category/menu.html.twig', array(
            'categories'    => $categories,
            'htmlTree'      => $htmlTree,
        ));
    }
```

All what i want to do is, to change the name of my link, i set ID out of , and this is the result : 
http://snapplr.com/snap/mkmv

It work perfectyl, right now i want to get the feild Title from the Entity CategoryTranslation of doctrine behaviors.

Thank